# Be able to check user private repo granted by OAuth token on github

Tags: git, github, oauth, permissions, repository

I am building an app along the Github rest api. I am trying to set in place a logic that allows the app to visite a user private repo on github. The app has already been granted permissions to get the user's private repo datas as commits, dates,... with a OAuth github access token.

The goal is to be able to visite the user's private repo on the github web interface. But unfortunatly when I try to access the repo (ex: https://github.com/owner/repo), obviously github prevents the app to do so. Is there a way to achieve this operation regarding the fact that the user granted me the access to his repo with an acess token?

Thank you!